# Zend application and bootstrap as non mvc

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible to use zend_application and zend_bootstrap as non mvc?
I'd like to use them but without the zend_view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can.

there is several way if you don't want to use zend view

1. don't invoke run() method of zend application, so request will not hit your zend controller, and no zend view will be instantiated :

   $application = new Zend_Application(
       APPLICATION_ENV,
       APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
   );

   $application->bootstrap();
2. disable view render & layout at controller

   ```
   $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
   $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just strip the appropriate resource parts from your application.ini

Further details

- [Zend Application - Theory of Operation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html)