# Zend Framework 2 Server & Non-MVC architecture

Tags: zend-framework2

I am aiming to have a more SOA oriented approach with ZF 2, where basically I drop the entire views in my architecture since they are of no use to me and load all of the Controllers and Models through a bootstrap file which points these all to a Server (Zend\Json\Server\Server). And although it's possible for MVC and SOA to co-exist, this is not really what my question is after.

I am finding Zend documentation relies too much on MVC applications, is anyone following any best practices for Non-MVC approaches within ZF2? I know my question might be a bit broad, what I am after specifically is to a similar approach to the question below which was asked for ZF1:

[Zend application and bootstrap as non mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980159/zend-application-and-bootstrap-as-non-mvc)

Of how to drop the views, but keep a consistency in the architecture to the one Zend Framework 2 suggests without going rogue or implementing a un-maintainable hybrid architecture.